# Non ideal op-amp equivalent circuit output voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, matlab

I am creating this question to ask you about a "strange" behavior I am observing in Matlab about an op-amp circuit. I am reading "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits" the 5th edition, and in the chapter about op-amps I was trying to solve the practice problem 5.1

[image]

I have tried to solve it analytically (by hand) and I couldn't get the results the authors give as solutions. Here are my two different attempts, the first one spanning 4 pages is a branch current method and the last (5th) image is the mesh current method: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Qyf.jpg.

To further confirm the results obtained I have modeled the circuit in Matlab in two different ways:

1) with a finite gain op-amp element: 
!Can't post the link to this image...

2) with a controlled voltage source and input/output resistances equivalent circuit:
!Can't post the link to this image...

The first model backs my results. The second model backs the authors results.

I know that the different results (8.99959 vs 9.0004) differ by less than 0.1% and that it probably wouldn't even be worth creating this question, but hey, this is not homework nor am I an Electrical Engineering student, I am just curious about why this is happening.

Well assuming I actually modeled an equivalent circuit, why is Matlab giving me two different results for the output voltage?

How come is my analytical result different from the authors? Did I make any error in my calculations?

Comment: 1) http://imgur.com/tZgkMdc

Comment: 2) http://imgur.com/mnYKep4

Comment: I'm not sure I totally follow your different models, but it looks to me like what you found is that the non-zero output impedance of the op-amp is the dominant source of gain errors in the circuit. Although it looks like you used a 50 ohm output resistance in that model, and that sounds like too high a value, even for a '741.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have said in my initial post that the Example 5.1 is in the previous page and it's an example where the authors use a 741 to build an inverting amplifier just to show how you can model an equivalent circuit for a non-ideal op-amp. The authors just give us the values for Ri, Ro and the open loop gain of the op-amp. I don't know where they got the values, the values may have just came out of the blue, but the authors tell us to use the same values for the Practice Problem 5.1

Answer (score 1):

The node voltage equations are not so difficult. But it's really a tedious work to type the equations. I got the same result with you, maybe we are both wrong :).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed an issue with the linked models:

### Your answer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftBMko.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Book answer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYZuKf.png)</sup>

At first I was very surprised the book got a "reasonable" answer considering it doesn't look like it has negative feedback for an ideal op-amp. However, consider what happens when Vout = 9.0004V (I'm going to ignore Ro and Ri for now, i.e. Ri = \$\infty\$ and Ro = 0):

\begin{equation}
V^+ = V_{out} \frac{ 5k\Omega}{45 k\Omega} = 1.000045V
\end{equation}
Checking this is compatible with the open-loop op-amp model:
\begin{equation}
V_{out} = G (V^+ - V^-) = 9.0004 V
\end{equation}

Out of pure serendipity this happens to be a "valid" solution. While this is a valid solution, it isn't at all stable and I suspect a more "accurate" op-amp model may be able to capture the stability issue more easily. Plugging a more "accurate" op-amp model into LTspice hints this is true: Vout clips to one of the rails (in my case it was the negative rail), as expected for op-amps with no negative feedback.

tl;dr: your answer is right. It remains right even after I plugged a more "accurate" op-amp model into LTspice. I also solved it algebraically using a computer and got the same answer as you (as well as diverger). However, the output is not at all understandable so I'm not going to post it.

Comment: I wonder where the "book answer" comes from? Apparently, it has a positive feedback.

Comment: @diverger Scout posted two links as comments to his question; the second one matches the "book" answer to every digit listed, so presumably the author used this one to find the answer. Of course, some other non-ideal effect might be at play, though I tried input current leakage and offset voltage and they just didn't line up so nicely.

Comment: I was also surprised that even though it should have positive feedback, the solution happens to be very close to the negative feedback solution.

Comment: I checked the 5th picture, the difference between the two method is: the former is node voltage method, and the latter is mesh current method, the structure of the circuit doesn't change. And they also give same result.

Comment: Yes and no, if you stare carefully at the OP's equations in picture 5 (particularly Eq. 4) you can see the convention assumes V+ is on the side of Rc/Rq, i.e. the sign convention of what I said was the "book's" answer.

Comment: Yes, the book's answer is derived from the second circuit, from that circuit i get the same result with the book.

Comment: After thinking about the ideal op-amp approximation as a VCVS, it is quite oblivious to negative or positive feedback! That is, I can write \$V = G (V^+-V^-)\$ as \$V = -G (V^--V^+)\$, then define a new \$V_2 = -V\$ to use in my equations. A hand-waving stability analysis seeing what would happen if I slightly increase/decrease Vout would lead to one answer being valid and stable (the negative feedback), and the other being valid but unstable (the positive feedback).

Comment: Good find! I didnt realize at the time this was a non ideal model, and after noticing it, ive been fiddling around with the equations but couldn't get it to match up.

Comment: I doubt that in reality, the second circuit may never get into the stable point which the book give us. The negative feedback is zero, but the positive feedback is not.

Comment: @diverger stability doesn't mean there isn't a valid solution, just don't expect to stay there for very long. Think of a similar problem of balancing a ball on top of a pencil point: yes, there exists a valid solution of where the ball is at the apex, but the slightest disturbance will cause it to fall, and in real life there are always distrubances.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the 'solution' exist no matter how soon it stay there.

Comment: In addition, one should be aware that some simulation runs (OP, DC and AC) even show a stable behaviour of the circuit with positive feedback. Only a TRAN analysis (time domain) can reveal the instability for real conditions. As another indication for instability, the phase characteristics (ac run) exhibits a rising function with frequency.

Comment: At this point I don't really know anything about stability (of op-amps! I know about the stability of slender columns though...), but I have taken my second Matlab model, the one with the VCVS and simply flipped the positive with the negative and obtained the same results as before (8.99959 for vo). However this goes against what the authors define as the equivalent circuit of a non-ideal op-amp where the negative side of the VCVS is connected to ground: http://i.imgur.com/9XRCmtx.jpg So I may be doing something wrong in my 2nd Matlab model and that's what I would like to know.

Comment: @Scout, as I have mentioned above - only a simulation in the time domain can reveal the instability of a circuit with positive feedback. As some other guys have stated already - there is one single (theoretical) stable solution only. However, under real conditions (power switch-on) such a circuit NEVER can have a stable operating point.

Comment: @LvW, well I just can't really take any advantage of what you have just wrote. You are probably right but at this point I have just no idea what the stability of an op-amp is. However I kept fiddling with my second model and, *sigh*, I think I have just found my mistake: I connected the input ports the wrong way. You see I assumed the current i1 flowed from the positive pole to the negative pole of vs (electron flow notation) and so the potential differential of Ri will be positive if I connect the negative input port of the VCVS to the top of Ri and the positive input port to the bottom of Ri

Comment: So my 2nd model should have been like this: http://i.imgur.com/bRJg1uU.jpg. This circuit gives the same answer of 8.99959. I'm really sorry for wasting your time with such a stupid mistake. So in short, does everyone agree that the authors results are wrong and that the right answer should be 8.99959?

Comment: @Scout, because you have "no idea what the stability of an opamp is" I can tell you that you always have to discriminate between (1) dc stabilty of an operating point and (2) dynamic ac stability against unwanted oscillations. Here we are discussing only case (1). Each opamp needs a fixed and stable dc operating poit that allows the output to swing in both directions - in response to a corresponding input signal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can see by inspection that the book answer must be in error, since the non-ideal factors that are introduced (finite gain and input resistance and output resistance) will **all** tend to decrease the gain from the ideal number of 9.0000.

Comment: Is this always true for an op-amp? If we consider non-ideal factors then the feedback gain will always be less than the ideal value? That is a real fast way to validate the results obtained if always true.

Comment: I can't think of any exceptions.. bias current, offset voltage, etc. either have no effect or reduce the gain.